# Pass IApp app variable to private methods from calling public method

Tags: c#, xamarin.uitest

Given the following code is in a file named Tests.cs:

```
public class Tests
{
    IApp app;
    Platform platform;

    public Tests(Platform platform)
    {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
    }

    [Test]
    public void AttemptInvalidLogin()
    {
        LandingPage landingPageObjects = new LandingPage();
        landingPageObjects.Login(app, "test123", "test123");
    }
}
```

The following code is in a file named LandingPage.cs:

```
public class LandingPage
{
    public void Login(IApp app, String Email, String Password)
    {
        LandingPageDisplayed(app);
        EnterEmailAddress(app, Email);
        EnterPassword(app, Password);
    }

    private void LandingPageDisplayed(IApp app)
    {
        app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("txtLogin").Text("Login"));
    }

    private void EnterEmailAddress(IApp app, String emailAddress)
    {
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("editvalidid"), emailAddress);
    }

    private void EnterPassword(IApp app, String password)
    {
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("editvalidpassword"), password);
    }

    private void TapLoginButton(IApp app)
    {
        app.Tap(c => c.Marked("btnlogin"));
    }
}
```

I am wanting to learn of a more efficient way to pass the variable "app" to the private methods inside LandingPage.cs. I tried setting IApp app in the LandingPage class, but when my code executes in Xamarin.UITests, app is being returned as undefined, and data is not entered. I also tried setting IApp app in the Tests class to public, but this does not work either.

The desired code would look similar to this:

```
public class LandingPage
{
    IApp app = Tests.app;
    public void Login(String Email, String Password)
    {
        LandingPageDisplayed();
        EnterEmailAddress(Email);
        EnterPassword(Password);
    }

    private void LandingPageDisplayed()
    {
        app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("txtLogin").Text("Login"));
    }

    private void EnterEmailAddress(String emailAddress)
    {
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("editvalidid"), emailAddress);
    }

    private void EnterPassword(String password)
    {
        app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("editvalidpassword"), password);
    }

    private void TapLoginButton()
    {
        app.Tap(c => c.Marked("btnlogin"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to inject the app in the constructor

```
IApp _app;
public LandingPage(IApp app) 
{
   _app = app;
}
```

and then methods..

```
private void LandingPageDisplayed()
{
   _app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("txtLogin").Text("Login"));
}
```

then in your tests

```
var  landingpage = new LandingPage(app);
```

Also, if your tests class is really `LandingPageTests`  then you may want

```
public class LandingPageTests
{
    IApp app;
    Platform platform;
    LandingPage _landingPage;

    public Tests(Platform platform)
    {
        this.platform = platform;
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void BeforeEachTest()
    {
        app = AppInitializer.StartApp(platform);
        _landingPage = new LandingPage(app);
    }

    [Test]
    public void AttemptInvalidLogin()
    {
        _landingPage.Login(app, "test123", "test123");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Keith. Your answer led me to getting this to work.

Just to be sure I understand correctly, this chunk of code:
    IApp _app;
    public LandingPage(IApp app) 
    {
      _app = app;
    }

Is instructing for this class to accept an object named app, and assigns the input to _app. 

Calling it via: 
    _landingPage = new LandingPage(app);

Passes the UI tree into the class to be used by the methods. Am I on the right track with this thought process?

Comment: in general for better designs, inject dependencies in via constructor and by an interface.   This then leads to using dependency injection frameworks etc